# Nightwatch mocha typescript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

Could someone please help me how to use mocha Nightwatch with typescript ,

if I use like below it's not working , please help  on it.

```js
import {NightwatchBrowser } from "nightwatch";

describe('Ecosia', function() {

  // test() and specify() is also available
  it('demo test', function(browser:NightwatchBrowser) {
    browser.url("https://test.com")
  });

});
```